# Touchscreen - configuration issue?

Tags: raspbian, display, software-installation, touchscreen

Good day!

I have a rpi B+ with 3,2" display (fb_ili9340) and XPT2046 touch controller. Previously 3.18.10, now 4.0.7 kernel.

Display works perfectly as with waveshare32b module, but no touchscreen by default. Then i load overlay in /boot/config.txt

> dtoverlay=ads7846,speed=500000,penirq=17,swapxy=1

device appears in lsmod

> ads7846                10636  0

and dmesg

> [    8.135143] ads7846 spi0.1: touchscreen, irq 411 
>   [    8.281637] input: ADS7846 Touchscreen as
>    /devices/platform/soc/20204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.1/input/input0
>   [   14.208572] fbtft_device:      ads7846 spi0.1 500kHz 8 bits
>    mode=0x00 
>   [   14.294753] fbtft_device:      ads7846 spi0.1 500kHz 8
>    bits mode=0x00

Then i tap screen, interrupts count increasing

> cat /proc/interrupts | grep ads
>   411:        433  pinctrl-bcm2835  17  ads7846

But nothing happens then i use evtest (touchscreen is symlink createt by /udev/rules.d/)

> sudo evtest /dev/input/touchscreen

and ts_calibrate is not functioning.

What i'm do wrong?

Comment: same issue with touchscreen 3.2 " from joyit